# how to get fields in a string List c#

Tags: c#, list

currently in c# i have a list of strings for each line in a text file.
In this file, there are fields separated by a comma.

```
string[] logFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> logList = new List<string>(logFile);
```

I don't really know what i have to do to obtain each field separately keeping in mind that the order of the field in the line matters.

Here is a example of lines from the file

```
406,14A,392D
1,IAW,A,,A,0.972177,0,0,-32767,32767,600.0,1,P
2,IBW,B,,A,0.972177,0,0,-32767,32767,600.0,1,P
3,ICW,C,,A,0.972177,0,0,-32767,32767,600.0,1,P
```

So what i want is to obtain each field to save it into its proper variable

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it a csv file? In that case there are dedicated readers for that.

Comment: is a configuration file from COMTRADE Standar (.CFG)

Comment: is the format always uniform?

Comment: Some example input would help

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish? Putting in an example in the question would be helpful!

Comment: Not sure why the question had a -1, people need to give new comers a chance before marking down their questions on negative points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can loop through the lines and use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to split each line in the separate fields

```
foreach(var field in logList)
{
    string [] allFieldsInLine = field.Split(',');
}
```

the order in `allFieldsInLine` will be the same as in your line.

In this line:

> 1,IAW,A,,A,0.972177,0,0,-32767,32767,600.0,1,P

`IAW` will be at `allFieldsInLine[1]`

at `allFieldsInLine[3]` will be `""` or `String.Empty`

Comment: maybe iterate afterwards over each field and .Trim() whitespace of the string

Comment: @Lukas this could be removed in the Split, but I am not sure about the 4-th value, may be it is empty on purpose

Comment: yeah it is empty on purpose, i'm gonna try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a List(String) I would create an Object class that accepts 12 different parameters (of type string) then add them to a List(Input) inputList.  Here is some example code that includes only 2 parameters.  Try and implement this in your own program.

Creating your object class:

```
 class Input
{
    private string thing1;
    private string thing2;

    public Input(string thing1, string thing2)
    {
        this.thing1 = thing1;
        this.thing2 = thing2;
    }
    public string Thing1 { get => thing1; set => thing1 = value; }
    public string Thing2 { get => thing2; set => thing2 = value; }
}
```

So now that you have created your object, you create a list of this Object.

```
List<Input> inputList = new List<Input>();
```

And finally, as you read through the text file you can create an Object that would contain each of those values in order and add them to inputList.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(text file);

string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{                 
   string[] useThis = line.Split(',');
   inputList.Add(new Input(useThis[0], useThis[1]);
}
```

Now whenever you want to reference the values you can either use a foreach loop to loop through the list or call it using

```
inputList.ElementAt[#].thing2
```

Hope this helps!